# Determine if a value from an array exists in another array in classic ASP

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I am very new to ASP, it is far from my language of choice, and is completely out of my comfort zone.

I have two arrays, and I need to determine easily if a value from the first array exists in the second array. How would I do this? I am not sure what to even search for!

I did create a function to determine if a value exists in an array, but thats as far as I can get:

```
Function in_array(element, arr)
    For i=0 To Ubound(arr) 
        If Trim(arr(i)) = Trim(element) Then 
            in_array = True
            Exit Function
        Else 
            in_array = False
        End If  
    Next 
End Function
```

Comment: Let me note: this is only going to be used for ONE-DIMENSIONAL arrays, it does not need to be over the top!

Comment: How big are these arrays?  Is either or both in sorted order?

Comment: any size, order does not matter - just merely checking to see if one or more values from Array 1 exist in Array 2..

Comment: Both do matter, if at least one array is sorted then a binary search can be used.  If both are very large then performance of your solution may be a problem.

Comment: oh okay - well we are dealing with arrays that will always have less than 50 elements in each - would that be okay? (like i said, not good with ASP!)

Comment: With just 50 elements you needn't worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, I was able to figure this out through a small bit of work, using my previous function!

Here is the solution for those interested:

```
Function in_array(element, arr)
    For i=0 To Ubound(arr) 
        If Trim(arr(i)) = Trim(element) Then 
            in_array = True
            Exit Function
        Else 
            in_array = False
        End If  
    Next 
End Function 

Function array_in_array(arr1, arr2)

    For i=0 To Ubound(arr1) 
        If in_array(arr1(i), arr2 ) Then 
            array_in_array = True
            Exit Function
        Else 
            array_in_array = False
        End If  
    Next 

End Function
```